# Custom Delegate with Modal Form Sheet not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have gone through most of the previous related posts, but although I have followed them correctly (as far as i understood), I simply am not able to trigger the delegate method for below code.

Objective: ModalView generates a string `*SQL_String`. Press DONE to dismiss the ModalView and trigger the delegate method in the parentview to get that `*SQL_String`.

> SearchModalViewController.h

```
@protocol SearchControllerDelegate
- (void)didDismissModalView:(NSString *)SQL_String;
@end

@interface SearchModalViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SearchControllerDelegate> searchDelegate;
- (IBAction)handleDone:(id)sender;
```

> SearchModalViewController.m

```
@interface SearchModalViewController ()
@end

@implementation SearchModalViewController
@synthesize searchDelegate;

- (IBAction)handleDone:(id)sender {
    [self dismissView:sender];
}

- (void)dismissView:(id)sender {
    [searchDelegate didDismissModalView:@"Test"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

> DetailViewController.m (My parent View Controller)

```
@interface DetailViewController () <SearchControllerDelegate>
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    SearchModalViewController *searchModal = [[SearchModalViewController alloc] init];
    searchModal.searchDelegate = self;
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

> Below delegate method is not getting triggered.

```
- (void)didDismissModalView:(NSString *)SQL_String {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"The string = %@", SQL_String);
}
```

Any idea where I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Thank you guys. With your fast suggestions, I am able to close it down by adding below code instead of my previous IB connection.

```
- (IBAction)showSearchModal:(id)sender {
    SearchModalViewController *searchModal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"search"];
    searchModal.searchDelegate = self;
    searchModal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    searchModal.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:searchModal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: can you show the code where you modally present the `SearchModalViewController`? why do you instantiate it locally within `viewDidLoad` already? doesn't that instance go away after `viewDidLoad` returns?

Comment: @nburk, I tried changing it to below, but the delegate is till nil.

property (strong) SearchModalViewController *SearchModal;

or 

interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <SearchControllerDelegate> {
    SearchModalViewController *SearchModal;
}

Comment: ok, please show the code where you call `presentViewContrller:`. and one more thing: please update your question with code rather than putting it into the comments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it goes

Change DetailViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)pushToSearch:(id)sender{
    SearchModalViewController *searchModal = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"search"];
    searchModal.searchDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:searchModal animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And it will work.

Comment: thanks a lot mate. Your help pointed me into right direction. I had to disconnect the connection to my modalview from IB and connected it programatically as you recommended. It worked.

Stackoverflow rocks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the delegate when you present the SearchModalViewController.  The reason why your code doesn't currently work, is because the modal view controller's delegate is nil.

**Update:**

You set the delegate in `prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)__unused sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"modalSearch"])
    {
        SearchModalViewController *controller = (SearchModalViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah the searchdelegate is nil in my case. I presented the SearchModalViewController through just IB without any code. Dragged the baritem SEARCH from detailviewcontroller to this ModalView as Segue: Modal, Presentation: Form Sheet and Transitio: Cross Dissolve. 

In this case, can you tell how/where i can set the delegate while presenting this modalview?

Comment: thanks a lot christian. Your help also pointed me to right direction. I changed the code to the one similar to what shivam recommended, and it worked.

Comment: No problem!  The way I showed is with an IB connection, but you can also do it programmatically.  Either way, the delegate is getting set now :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure your `dismissView:` of the `SearchModalViewController` is getting triggered.

Secondly, make sure your `searchDelegate` in the `dismissView:` method is not `nil`.